# Unable to invoke method declared in WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have created the WCF service and consumed that service into my client side application and I'm unable to invoke the method.

**the following exception is occured:**

```
{"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."}
```

I think there is the some issue with the binding. I had googled but didn't find any solution. Please guide me how can I fix this issue. Help will be appreciate.

Thanks

**Code Snippet:**

**Service Web.Config**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
     <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Index.aspx**

```
  private void process() 
    {
        TestRef.EmployeeDC o = new TestRef.EmployeeDC();
        o.userID = signInEmail;
        o.companyID = signInPassword;

        //ServiceReference.EmployeeDC p = new ServiceReference.EmployeeDC();


        //Service Call
        TestRef.TestServClient tsc = new TestRef.TestServClient();
        tsc.callBusinessLayer(o); // here im getting the exception

        Debug.Print(""+signInEmail);
    }
```

**Client Side Web.Config**

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestServ" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestServ1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/Publish/TestServ.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestServ" contract="ServiceReference.ITestServ"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestServ" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/Publish/TestServ.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestServ1" contract="TestRef.ITestServ"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestServ1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What about following the error message advice?

turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs

Comment: Check that ABC (Address, Binding and Contract) for service and client match. Debug/turn on tracing on both server and client [here is how](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).